# JavaScript - Form submit to window.open popup not working IE/FF

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("target" , "previewWindow")
    form.setAttribute("action", "partner_api/preview.php");

    var pidField = document.createElement("input");
    pidField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    pidField.setAttribute("name", "pid");
    pidField.setAttribute("value", "<?php echo $partnerID; ?>");
    form.appendChild(pidField);

    var bidField = document.createElement("input");
    bidField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    bidField.setAttribute("name", "bid");
    bidField.setAttribute("value", boxID);
    form.appendChild(bidField);

    window.open('', 'previewWindow', 'width=235,height=500,left=100,top=100');
    form.submit();
```

Hi,

I have problem with code above - it does work prefectly on Chrome, but doesn't on Firefox and IE.
What is supposed to do, is to submit created form to new popup window, but on FF/IE it just leaves blank window.

Is there any fix to that?

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: If it will work at all, you need to give it a chance to do so: `window.open('', 'previewWindow'); setTimeout(function(){     form.submit();},1000);`

Comment: There is no error.
Timeout still doesn't do. It is still not working on IE and FF.

Comment: I actually found solution - if anyone needs it.

It is required to add form to document to make it work.

    document.documentElement.appendChild(form);

It fixed the issue on IE/FF.

Comment: Great. good you posted that before I wrote my suggestion of simply document.write the form into the new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found solution - if anyone needs it. It is required to add form to document to make it work. document.documentElement.appendChild(form); It fixed the issue on IE/FF

Comment: can you put the complete code? I have a similar issue here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937329/submit-form-in-popup-window-does-not-work-in-firefox-and-ie8-ie9/30937702?noredirect=1#comment49911002_30937702] but I don't find how to apply your fix

Answer (score 0):

For future readers : Check this function in  JS to submit a from and open an new tab.

```
             function postData() {

                var ElementValue = document.getElementById('Id of element').value;

                var form = document.getElementById("formName");
                form.setAttribute("method", "post");
                form.setAttribute("action", "Your Url");
                form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

                var NewElement = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenFieldSerialNo.setAttribute("input", "hidden");
                hiddenFieldSerialNo.setAttribute("name", "ElementName");
                hiddenFieldSerialNo.setAttribute("value", ElementValue);

                form.appendChild(NewElement);
                document.documentElement.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();

              }
```