# Submit form in popup window does not work in Firefox and IE8/IE9

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this simple way to submit a form in a pop up window (which need to be done with vanilla JS)

```
<form onsubmit="CheckoutProducts.onSubmitForm(this);" action="/product/"
method="post" name="paymentForm" id="paymentForm">
```

and this is my JS code

```
var CheckoutProducts = CheckoutProducts || {
    onSubmitForm: function(form) {
        window.open('', 'formpopup','width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
        form.target = 'formpopup';
        document.paymentForm.submit();
    }
}
```

It is working fine in Chrome, but for some reason it is not working in Firefox and IE, it just opens the pop up with the blank page, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the console for any error messages and post them here

Comment: There is not any error on the console @Guillemo Mansilla

Answer (score 1):

Very simple would be to use tested component that works in all major browsers in the same way.

```js
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Margus for your answer , but this need to be done with vanilla JS so it does not depend of external frameworks/libraries like jQuery, also what is wanted is use popup instead modals

Comment: Well then I recomend you try ( http://www.avtex.com/blog/2012/01/26/cross-browser-css-only-modal-box/ )